# Errno 185090050 _ssl.c:343: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib, after packaging to exe by PyInstaller

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, pyinstaller, google-api-python-client

I code a python script to check files in GCS, it uses wxpython to generate the GUI. To authenticate I did it in this way(following the way in Google sample code -> http://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform-samples/source/browse/file-transfer-json/chunked_transfer.py?repo=storage):

```
flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, 
                                # the secrets file I put in same folder
                               scope=scope,
                               message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

credential_storage = CredentialStorage(CREDENTIALS_FILE) # the file to store
                                                    # authentication credentials
credentials = credential_storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run_oauth2(flow, credential_storage)

self.printLog('Constructing Google Cloud Storage service...')
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
return discovery_build('storage', 'v1beta1', http=http)
```

The codes above are contained in my Python script, which works very well when it is just a python .py file, later I used pyinstaller convert it to .exe in win 7 64bit(I also put the secret file in the same folder as the .exe file) using below command

> C:\gcs_file_check>python pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller.py -w
>   gcs_file_check.py

When clicking on the exe, the **Request for Permission page** from Google was launched correctly(as what it is as running Python script not exe), but after I click Accept, the above code will throw exception:

> [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:343: error:0B084002:x509 certificate
>   routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib

And I can see the file **credentials.json** is not created by .exe, while the Python script can create this file correctly.

Could someone know how this happens and how to fix? Appreciate every answer!

===================

updated on 04/16:

I added debugging code and found that the exception exactly comes from below code:

```
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run_oauth2(flow, credential_storage)
```

===================

updated:

Add more detail, previously I was using **oauth2client.tools.run()**

```
from oauth2client.tools import run as run_oauth2
```

Now I change to run_flow() as the source code suggested -> https://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.tools-pysrc.html#run

```
from oauth2client.tools import run_flow as run_oauth2
```

Now this part of code is:

```
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__,                  
                     formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
                     parents=[tools.argparser] )
                     flags = tools.argparser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run_oauth2(flow, credential_storage, flags)
```

**But still**, the python code works well, and throw the same exception [Errno 185090050] after packaging to .exe by PyInstaller.

Comment: Not sure if it is the root cause here, but scripts run from inside of EXE packagers often have a different "current directory" set than the same script run outside of the package. I'd recommend printing os.getcwd() right before that code.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I add the code os.getcwd() but did not see anything strange. Later I added debugging code and found that the exception comes from the code: if credentials is None or credentials.invalid: credentials = run_oauth2(flow, credential_storage), updated in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/557
"I also faced a similar error when using pyinstaller with Httplib2.
You need to explicitly pass the path to ssl client cert file to the 'cert' argument http request. Also, you would need to package your. .pem file as a data file in pyinstaller."