# Requests.exceptions.SSLError: Errno 185090050

Tags: python, ssl, py2exe

Im trying to make a .py in .exe. In .py the application works fine but after I build it in .exe using py2exe I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "filename.py", line 210, in <module>
File "requests\api.pyc", line 55, in get
File "requests\api.pyc", line 44, in requests
File "requests\sessions.pyc", line 461, in request
File "requests\sessions.pyc", line 567, in send
File "requests\adapters.pyc", line 399, in send
requests.exceptions.SLLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:344: error: 0B084002:x509 certificate routines: X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

And the line 210 in file is this

```
r2 = requests.get('https://www.hitbox.tv/api/chat/servers', timeout=timeoutDefault)
```

The setup.py is this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['filename.py'])
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Related: [Errno 185090050 _ssl.c:343: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib, after packaging to exe by PyInstaller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073709/errno-185090050-ssl-c343-error0b084002x509-certificate-routinesx509-load-c).

Answer (score 5):

The `requests` module (or actually `urllib3` below it) fails to open the CA certificates file.

If you don't want to verify the server's certificate, you can change the call to:

```
r2 = requests.get('https://www.hitbox.tv/api/chat/servers', 
                  timeout=timeoutDefault, verify=False)
```

If you care about certificates (and you should), make sure that CA certs file is bundled with your application. According to the `requests` documentation:

> You can also pass verify the path to a CA_BUNDLE file for private
>   certs. You can also set the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE environment variable.
>
> Requests can also ignore verifying the SSL certificate if you set
>   verify to False.

See here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

Comment: Thanks! But I solved the problem by deleting the s from the http :D

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this by monkey-patching `requests` to pass `cacert.pem`:

```
def _monkey_patch_requests():
    orig_send = HTTPAdapter.send
    def _send_no_verify(self, request, stream=False, timeout=None, verify=True, cert=None, proxies=None):
        return orig_send(self, request, stream, timeout, 'cacert.pem' if verify else False, cert, proxies)
    HTTPAdapter.send = _send_no_verify

_monkey_patch_requests()
```

and copying `<Python>/Lib/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem` to `dist`.

Comment: There is no need to patch the code.  You can pass the path to the cacert.pem file as the value of the verify parameter: `requests.get('https://www.hitbox.tv/', verify='path/to/cacert.pem')`

Comment: @nmgeek If the `requests.get` call is in third-party code, monkey patching is easier.

Comment: That's fair _if_ requests.get is called from third-party code.  In the question it's in filename.py (on line 210) and that looks like it is part of CosminZoRR's application code.